# CoreData: annotation: PostSaveMaintenance: incremental_vacuum with freelist_count - 52 and pages_to_free 10

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am getting this warning. Can anyone help me understand what exactly this means ?

```
CoreData: annotation: PostSaveMaintenance: incremental_vacuum with freelist_count - 52 and pages_to_free 10
```

Comment: What symptoms or problems are you observing in your app?

Comment: Actual I haven't faced any problems yet. I don't know if there are problems, have to use the app for some time and check.

Comment: I'm also getting this, except mine says a much larger number ```...with freelist_count - 20959 and pages_to_free 20923```. Nothing breaking, just prints to console for some reason... Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: No I still did not get any info on that.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974045/coredata-annotation-postsavemaintenance-incremental-vacuum-with-freelist-coun/71587211?noredirect=1#comment126524145_71587211, but has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This message is due to Core Data undergoing a VACUUM operation in order to free up space in the Sqlite database. More information [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). It is normal to see this message.